# Unable to add 100hz output with xrandr

Tags: hdmi, xrandr

My TV supports 100/120hz output. I tried the following commands to add the mode:

find the magic numbers:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080 100
# 1920x1080 99.90 Hz (CVT) hsync: 114.58 kHz; pclk: 302.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_100.00"  302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync
```

Add the new mode:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_100" 302.50  1920 2072 2280 2640  1080 1083 1088 1147 -hsync +vsync
```

have a look at xrandr to check the mode is created correctly:

```
1920x1080_100 (0xec)  302.5MHz
h: width  1920 start 2072 end 2280 total 2640 skew    0 clock  114.6KHz
v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1147           clock   99.9Hz
```

Now to the good part, add the mode to my HDMI output:

```
$ xrandr --addmode DFP2 1920x1080_100
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  157 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  32
Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

I did the same for 120Hz, same issue.
Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: nope can't get it to work. maybe I'm trying something that can't be done?

Answer (score 2):

This

```
$ xrandr --addmode DFP2 1920x1080_100
```

should be:

```
$ xrandr --addmode DFP2 1920x1080_100.00
```

cheers